# Youtube copyrights and adult video load protection

Tags: algorithm, youtube, youtube-api

**Prerequisites:**
I write service one of the possibilities of which allow users load video at my channel.  But how I can check that the video is correct ( it not violates copyrights and not contain adult video or something similar ).
 One of decision, check loaded content manually ( but it's take a lot of time ).
 Another variant provide for users google authorization and it can load at my chanel by own account ( but not every user have google account, and maybe user not want to upload video by own account ).

**Questions:**

1. Does youtube provide ability to check loaded video automaticaly before it's will be public?
2. Are there any services, or library that verify content for this criteries? ( but it most likely assume load video on third-party service or own server and load video to youtube after that assumes overhead traffic charges and double waiting time)
3. How solve this problem most efficienty ?

Comment: There is a good library OpenCV. This is a real thing, but you need a good coder to done this dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2071959 and naun.org/main/NAUN/computers/20-462.pdf – user3811082

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not difficult to solve. But you need a good coder with a good knowledge of image processing libraries (OpenCV for example) to do something satisfactory. The algorithm should be based on image processing, skin detector, and pattern recognition techniques. [Here is a good explanation of it.](http://www.naun.org/main/NAUN/computers/20-462.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, it solve problem, but maybe exists third-party service or maybe youtube api provide facilities to hadle this with out load video at my server, split it by frames and check frame with some intervals for certains criteries. ( It's сarries the overhead of traffi, and gratest waiting time before user can see it video at public environment). I'm hope that i find more lightweight solution.